# Android sharelock library error

Tags: android, shared-libraries

I have dowloaded sharelock library file and now I had made new project. When I am going to add this library, it's giving me error like this in console

```
[2013-06-03 04:49:41 - SharelockDeemo] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,<br>
[2013-06-03 04:49:41 - SharelockDeemo] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).<br>
[2013-06-03 04:49:41 - SharelockDeemo] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.<br>
[2013-06-03 04:49:41 - SharelockDeemo] Versions found are:<br>
[2013-06-03 04:49:41 - SharelockDeemo] Path: D:\AndroidTool\workspace\librarySharelock\libs\android-support-v4.jar<br>
[2013-06-03 04:49:41 - SharelockDeemo]  Length: 271754<br>
[2013-06-03 04:49:41 - SharelockDeemo]  SHA-1: 53307dc2bd2b69fd5533458ee11885f55807de4b<br>
[2013-06-03 04:49:41 - SharelockDeemo] Path: D:\AndroidTool\workspace\SharelockDeemo\libs\android-support-v4.jar<br>
[2013-06-03 04:49:41 - SharelockDeemo]  Length: 484258<br>
[2013-06-03 04:49:41 - SharelockDeemo]  SHA-1: bd6479f5dd592790607e0504e66e0f31c2b4d308<br>
[2013-06-03 04:49:41 - SharelockDeemo] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies<br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally solve this

import library folder-> then create new project simply attch library file from properties remove project jar file and its work

before i had attche jar file library and project but it will not work

Answer (score 2):

have you tried using the same .jar file for both your application and Actionbarsherlok libarary? You should either use the one in app's lib folder. or the one in library's lib folder

Comment: ya check library has no error but in project it will not import sharelock files

Comment: how you tried importing it? did you created a project from existing source code using sherlok library folder?

Comment: ya i had create new project and attch library from properties whern i attch it attach but when i reopen project it display red cross error in attching library

Answer (score 1):

**Delete android-support-v4.jar file** from either actionbarsherlock library or from your demo project will solve your problem

Comment: make sure you have target android 4.0 sdk version for actionbarsherlock librarary

Comment: android:targetSdkVersion="17" when i attcha libray in project projeper it will attach very well but when i reopen it will display red cross erro like library has error like

Comment: dont delete android-support.jar from actionbarsherlock librarary project jsut delete it from the project in which u will add actionbarsherlock library.ok

Comment: there is some problem in library

Comment: have you checked ISlibrary while adding actionbarsherlock library to your project

Comment: ya i had not remove jar file from library i had just remove jar file from my project but when i attch library in my project it attch but when i rechect project in library then it give error

Comment: just build path of actionbarsherlock library and in android build path select andorid 4.0 version then clean library project then add to your project

Comment: no in my project i had not check true just check true in library only

Comment: its ok that not issue dont check it.try my previous comment suggestion

Answer (score 1):

remove `android-support-v4.jar` from your project

Comment: either will do but remove from project,

Comment: i had remove from project it will not give me error but it will not import sharelock files

Comment: make sure in your project properties you have imported sherlock library

Comment: in project.properties there is: android.library.reference.1=../librarySharelock
is it right?

Comment: i had attche library file in project but in attchament there is givin red cross error

Comment: Make sure that the sherlock library is your workspace where your project is. the red cross appears when sherlock library is somewhere else. Copy the sherlock library to your workspace where your project is, then import the library and then apply it to your project.

Comment: Thanks for reply that why i had up vote and  now it's work there is some proble so it give error not its fine